# Regex to find occurrences of all numbers in text in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need a Regex to find occurrences of all decimal numbers in a given text in jquery
for example if my input text is

hello world 123.98 how 2542.265 are you

then needed output is an array arr[]

with arr[0] = 123.98
and a[1] = 2542.265

I have tried following
but not working

```
var str = "hello world 123.98 how 2542.26 are you";
var patt1 = /[0-9][.][0-9]/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
```

It gives output as 3.9,2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `+` (1 or more) quantifier to the number collections. You can also replace `[0-9]` by `\d`. It means the same.

```js
var str = "hello world 123.98 how 2542.26 are you";
var patt1 = /\d+.\d+/g;
while ((result = patt1.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Match "${result[0]}" found at index ${result.index}`);
}
```

Comment: can we have any method to get their indexes also ?
for example 12 and 22 in above case

Comment: @nextdeveloper you can do that with the `RegExp.exec()` method. See my updated answer.